# System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, printing, printdialog

I'm trying to print some user control in wpf.

It does work on my computer, but on another computer it doesn't.
My computer is windows 10, the other computer is windows 7, both have latest framework update.

The application is closing before it gets to

```
if(printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
```

This is the code:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    printDialog.PrintVisual(border, "Treatment Form");
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: That question is related to windows forms, i'm using wpf

Comment: What's the exact version of framework ?